# Web address virtual directory breaks external javascript link so it cannot find the files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

so i have a little problem
my webadress looks a little like this:

```
http://localhost:23425/dynamicName/Home.aspx
```

the dynamicName part well....will be dynamically named. So because of that it breaks my

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.js"> </script>
```

scripts since it can't find it. however if its

```
http://localhost:23425/Home.aspx
```

then the javascript works.

So my question is how can i get the javascript to work on the dynamic virtual directory and not have my links be broken?

i've tried this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/Menu.js")%>"> </script>
```

with the script links and the css links but it doesn't seem to do it. just a grey box drops down with no content.
Any help will be extremely apprectiated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/Menu.js") %>
```

`ResolveClientUrl` creates a path which includes `../`. That may be your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think i've tried it before, but when i click on the button that should then load the content it just makes a grey box wheere the content should be but no content. Should I also surround my css files with the ResolveUrl?

Comment: Actually, seems as though I'm getting a DOM exception when clicking on the button when I go into chrome inspect element

Comment: Pretty much anything that is content should be loaded this way. Images, CSS, scripts, etc.

Comment: yes thank you very much I got it working, seems as though i never had one of the big javascript files in another aspx file surrounded with the ResolveUrl so it was broken. Thank you so much for your help